# System.web.dll - will be updated in regular Server microsoft updates?

Tags: asp.net, performance, datagridview, operating-system, production-environment

Will **SYSTEM.WEB.DLL** be updated with regular microsoft updates ? if so will it impact any ASP.NET application built on framework 2.0 / 3.5 in terms of performance while triggering event methods like **ONROWCREATED** ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The file is included in the .NET Framework. So it will be updated when the framework is updated - you as a developer choose newer version of the target framework in Visual Studio

Comment: @xmojmr : thanks, understood that. But my case is related to performance of an application in production for a client which was running fine all this time but only recently it developed a slowness issue on a particular page and the root cause is identified as delay in ONROWCREATED  even trigger. Since it belongs to System.Web assembly and that there were no level application patches released / deployed for past 2 years, I have a strong feeling that it could be due to changes related to System.web.dll. Plz help